# f# - how to serialize option and DU as value or null (preferably with json.net)

Tags: serialization, f#, json.net

How can i get my json from web api to format only value or null for Option types and Discriminated Unions preferably using Newtonsoft.

I am currently using Newtonsoft and only have to add this to web api for it to work:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings <- new JsonSerializerSettings()
```

When i consume the data on my side, i can easily convert it back to an F# item using:  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'a>(json)`

The api will be consumed by NON .NET clients as well so i would like a more standard formatted json result.

I would like to to fix my issue, w/o having to add code or decorators to all of my records/DU in order for it to work.  I have lots of records with lots of properties, some are Option.

ex (this is how DU is serializing):

```
// When value
"animal": {
  "case": "Dog"
}

// When no value
"animal": null
```

This is what I need:

```
// When value 
"animal": "Dog"

// When no value 
"animal": null
```

This is how an Option type is serializing:

```
"DocumentInfo": {
  "case": "Some",
  "fields": [
    {
      "docId": "77fb9dd0-bfbe-42e0-9d29-d5b1f5f0a9f7",
      "docType": "Monkey Business",
      "docName": "mb.doc",
      "docContent": "why cant it just give me the values?"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what I need:

```
"DocumentInfo": {
   "docId": "77fb9dd0-bfbe-42e0-9d29-d5b1f5f0a9f7",
   "docType": "Monkey Business",
   "docName": "mb.doc",
   "docContent": "why cant it just give me the values?"
}
```

Thank you :-)

Comment: In addition to the answer I gave two weeks ago, I just found out about [FSharpLu](https://github.com/Microsoft/fsharplu/wiki), which includes simpler serialization for options. I have no experience with it so I can't give you more details, but it may be worth a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution that allows me to use Newtonsoft (JSON.NET), apply custom converters for my types where needed and not require any changes to my DU's or Records.

The short answer is, create a custom converter for Json.Net and use the Read/Write Json overrides:

```
type CustomDuConverter() =
    inherit JsonConverter()  (...)
```

Unfortunately the ones I have found online that were already created doesn't work as is for my needs listed above, but will with slight modification.  A great example is to look at: https://gist.github.com/isaacabraham/ba679f285bfd15d2f53e

To apply your custom serializer in Web Api for every call, use:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new CustomDuConverter())
```

To deserialize use (example that will deserialize to DU):

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Animal>("Dog", customConverter)
```

ex:

```
type Animal = Dog | Cat
```

json:

```
"animal": "Dog"
```

This will allow you to create a clean Api for consumers and allow you to consume 3rd party Json data into your types that use Option, etc.

Comment: What do you do if you have a mixture of C# and F# code with WebApi? You want to leave the C# objects as they are, and handle the F# using the CustomDuConverter.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using [Chiron](https://github.com/xyncro/chiron). I haven't used it myself so I can't give you an extensive example, but https://neoeinstein.github.io/blog/2015/12-13-chiron-json-ducks-monads/index.html has some bits of sample code. (And see https://neoeinstein.github.io/blog/2016/04-02-chiron-computation-expressions/index.html as well for some nicer syntax). Basically, Chiron knows how to serialize and deserialize the basic F# types (strings, numbers, options, etc.) already, and you can teach it to serialize any other type by providing that type with two static methods, `ToJson` and `FromJson`:

```
static member ToJson (x:DocumentInfo) = json {
    do! Json.write "docId" x.docId
    do! Json.write "docType" x.docType
    do! Json.write "docName" x.docName
    do! Json.write "docContent" x.docContent
}
static member FromJson (_:DocumentInfo) = json {
    let! i = Json.read "docId"
    let! t = Json.read "docType"
    let! n = Json.read "docName"
    let! c = Json.read "docContent"
    return { docId = i; docType = t; docName = n; docContent = c }
}
```

By providing those two static methods on your `DocumentInfo` type, Chiron will automatically know how to serialize a `DocumentInfo option`. At least, that's my understanding -- but the Chiron documentation is sadly lacking (by which I mean literally *lacking*: it hasn't been written yet), so I haven't really used it myself. So this may or may not be the answer you need, but hopefully it'll be of some help to you even if you don't end up using it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, unfortunately this does not seem that it will work due to the fact that I just want to plug something into the pipeline - i have A LOT of records & DU's with many properties and don't want to have to create a a serialize/deserialize for every one of them for some specific library.  I will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: I just found https://github.com/haf/Newtonsoft.Json.FSharp, but the repo comment suggests that it isn't developed any longer and recommends using Chiron instead. However, it *might* be enough for your needs.